# PHPEclipse vs PDT

Tags: php, ide, eclipse-pdt, phpeclipse

It looks like these are both comparable packages for doing PHP development in Eclipse - what are their relative advantages and disadvantages?

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=PHPEclipse+vs+PDT

Comment: As everything is relative, both have as well relative advantages and disadvantages to each other. You should probably ask for something you want to learn about and write what is important for you to have in a IDE.

Comment: Thanks @hsz, that exact search led me here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the chart on the PHPEclipse Website's Wiki, the main difference apparently is that PDT uses Zend Debugger while PHPEclipse features DBG.

http://www.phpeclipse.com/wiki/Comparison_Chart

Answer (score 4):

[This blog post](http://blog.whitelionsoft.com/blog/2008/04/11/php-for-eclipse-phpeclipse-vs-pdt) has a lot of info comparing the two, although it's obviously biased towards PHPEclipse.

The author notes that the history of the two, with PHPEclipse having a longer history than PDT.  PHPEclipse is totally community contributed (of devs who mainly program in PHP doing Java) while PDT is developed by the Zend team.

In the comments, some people complain that PHPEclipse's main web page does it a disservice and makes it look it is no longer maintained.  Others, often state they prefer PDT because of the auto-complete features.

Comment: I've added a summary.